# Move Picturebox inside TableLayoutPanel from one cell to the other with delay

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox, tablelayoutpanel

I have a TableLayoutPanel inside a Form and that TableLayoutPanel has five Picturebox controls inside some of its cells. What I would like to do is, move those Pictureboxes to different cells based on a list of coordinates passed as an argument. From user perspective, those Pictureboxes will disappear from one cell and reappear in another cell.(Just like a main character in tile base game where the character disappear in one cell and reappear in an adjacent cell). The update method is inside Form class and it is called by a method from another class. The problem is, it does not display each movement. It just shows initial positions of all Pictureboxes followed by some refreshing and then the final position. It should display PictureBoxes in each coordinates before it gets to the final coordinate. I tried Thread.Sleep() but it doesn't work. How do I resolve this issue?

```
public partial class CheckerBoard : Form
{
   ....
   ....
   public void update(Position k, List<Position> p)                
   { 

        p1_picturebox.Visible = false;
        p2_picturebox.Visible = false;
        p3_picturebox.Visible = false;
        p4_picturebox.Visible = false;
        p5_picturebox.Visible = false;

        // Load images in new positions            

        this.board.Controls.Add(k_picturebox, k.col, knight.row);
        this.board.Controls.Add(p1_picturebox, p[0].col, p[0].row);
        this.board.Controls.Add(p2_picturebox, p[1].col, p[1].row);
        this.board.Controls.Add(p3_picturebox, p[2].col, p[2].row);
        this.board.Controls.Add(p4_picturebox, p[3].col, p[3].row);
        this.board.Controls.Add(p5_picturebox, p[4].col, p[4].row);  

        ------UPDATED---------
        this.Invalidate();
        Thread.Sleep(3000);

   }
}
```

**UPDATE**
I fixed my code as per suggestions. However, the problem still persists. Seems that it is redrawing the whole tablelayoutpanel instead of moving picture box from one cell to the other. I can see the refreshing of the tablelayoutpanel.

```
    private void replay(State currentState)
    {            
        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer
        {
            Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5)
        };
        timer.Tick += (o, e) =>
        {
            List<Position> pos = new List<Position>();

            foreach(Position p in currentState.pawns)
            {
                pos.Add(p);
            }

            this.update(currentState.knight, pos);
            currentState = currentState.next;
            if (currentState == null)
            {
                timer.IsEnabled = false;
                //this.prepareDisplay();
            }
        };
        timer.IsEnabled = true;


    }


    public void update(Position knight, List<Position> pawns)                
    { 
        // Load images in new positions            
        this.board.Controls.Remove(knight_picturebox);
        this.board.Controls.Add(knight_picturebox, knight.col, knight.row);

        for(int i=0; i < pawns.Count; i++)
        { 
            //this.board.Controls.Add(this.picBoxList[i], pawns[i].col, pawns[i].row);
            this.picBoxList[i].WaitOnLoad = true;
            this.board.Controls.Remove(this.picBoxList[i]);
            this.board.Controls.Add(this.picBoxList[i], pawns[i].col, pawns[i].row);
        }

    }
```

**UPDATE**
With suspendLayout and improveLayout, redrawing is improved. But I'm wondering if it is possible not to redraw the tablelayout but just the pictureboxes so that it appears only the pictureboxes are moving.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms? WPF? ASP? ...?? __Always__ tag your question accordingly!
 - Instead of Thread.Sleep you ought to use a Timer to do animations in winforms.

Comment: Calling Sleep() in a GUI program is a very bad idea, you never want the thread that responds to user input and keeps the window updated to go catatonic.   You'll get ahead by calling `this.Update();` before you go to sleep.  But learning how to use Timer needs to be next.  Followed by learning what a "game loop" looks like.

Comment: @TaW It's Winform. I updated the tag.

Comment: @Hans Passant : I tried sleep after calling update but the result is exactly the same. I'll look into timer.

Comment: Time does not work unfortunately. Im not sure where I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works. Assuming that you have made the temporary list of the names of the pictureboxes into List from where you can retrieve the names and find them to move to another position. So, basically in my method you are simply shifting their positions to another cells in your tablelayout panel.
You can optimize it by using "foreach" loop to retrieve pictureboxes instead of iterating the same Controls.Find() function for each control.name of picturebox.

```
public void update(Position k, List<Position> p)
    {
        PictureBox p1 = this.Controls.Find("/* the picturebox name*/", true).FirstOrDefault() as PictureBox;
        PictureBox p2 = this.Controls.Find("/* the picturebox name*/", true).FirstOrDefault() as PictureBox;
        PictureBox p3 = this.Controls.Find("/* the picturebox name*/", true).FirstOrDefault() as PictureBox;
        PictureBox p4 = this.Controls.Find("/* the picturebox name*/", true).FirstOrDefault() as PictureBox;
        PictureBox p5 = this.Controls.Find("/* the picturebox name*/", true).FirstOrDefault() as PictureBox;
        this.board.Controls.Remove(p1);
        this.board.Controls.Remove(p2);
        this.board.Controls.Remove(p3);
        this.board.Controls.Remove(p4);
        this.board.Controls.Remove(p5);

        //p1_picturebox.Visible = false;
        //p2_picturebox.Visible = false;
        //p3_picturebox.Visible = false;
        //p4_picturebox.Visible = false;
        //p5_picturebox.Visible = false;

        // Load images in new positions            

        //this.board.Controls.Add(k_picturebox, k.col, knight.row);
        this.board.Controls.Add(p1, p[0].col, p[0].row);
        this.board.Controls.Add(p2, p[1].col, p[1].row);
        this.board.Controls.Add(p3, p[2].col, p[2].row);
        this.board.Controls.Add(p4, p[3].col, p[3].row);
        this.board.Controls.Add(p5, p[4].col, p[4].row);

        //alternatively for the whole above code you may optimize like below.
        int i = 0;
        foreach(Control c in PictureBoxList)    //PictureBoxList is retrieved as List<Control>
        {
            PictureBox p1 = this.Controls.Find(c.Name, true).FirstOrDefault() as PictureBox;
            p1.Name = c.Name;   //assign new name from the same list which contains pictureboxes and can get name by using c.Name
            this.board.Controls.Remove(p1);
            this.board.Controls.Add(p1, p[i].col, p[i].row);
            i++;
        }


        ------UPDATED-------- -
        this.Invalidate();
        Thread.Sleep(3000);

    }
```

**Update:**

> Have you tried setting the **WaitOnLoad** property of Picturebox to **true**?

**Update2:**

> Try invalidating the **board** and then the **new pictureBoxes** particularly.

Comment: I did but doesn't fix the problem. You can see it in my updated code.

Comment: Are you looking to update whole tablelayout in form?? I mean are there any other controls placed in the tablelayout apart from the ones you need to move??